# understanding Krylov-Bogolubov Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, ergodic-theory

Could anyone tell me what is $P(x,dy)$ and $P^{n+1}(x,dy)$ means here in [1](http://www.hairer.org/notes/Markov.pdf)p- 30, in the proof of thm 4.17? And, why $\phi$ was taken bounded by $1$? Are all $P^k(x,A)$, $P$, $Q^n$ probability measure on $(X, B(X))$? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each fixed $x$ $P(x,A)$ is a probability measure and the integral of $f$ w.r.t. this measure is written as $\int f(y)P(x,dy)$. Similar interpretation holds for $\int f(y)P^{n}(x,dy)$.

Comment: Then what is $P$ he mentioned there as a Feller transition probability in the statement of the theorem? It would be great if you write the definition of Feller transition probability. Also, is he just taking same notation for $P$ and $P(x, \cdot)$? Thanks!

Comment: A transition probability is a function $P(x,A)$ which is a probability measure for each fixed $x$ and a measurable function of $x$ for each fixed $A$. For definition of Feller transition probability see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feller_process